# After not running monerod for a couple of weeks, it throws me errors and closes before I can read them. What is my strategy here?

Tags: monerod, loglevel

First time I saw something about not finding i2p, but now other errors are listed, but as I say, the program closes too quickly for me to read them.

Naturally, I left the default logging at zero. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To investigate this problem you have to perform the following steps:

Note that this assumes you are using Windows.

First, browse to the directory `monerod` is located in. Second, open t he command prompt. You can do this by using SHIFT + right click simultaneously. It will give you an option to "Open command window here". Make sure your cursor isn't located on any of the files. Third, after the command prompt is opened, type the following command:

`monerod.exe --log-level 2`

This command will start monerod with log level 2. Lastly, paste the output of the log to https://paste.fedoraproject.org such that the developers can investigate your problem.

---

For Linux and Mac OS X:

First, browse to the directory `monerod` is located in. Second, use right click and it will give you an option to "Open terminal". Alternatively, you can open a terminal and cd to `monerod`'s location. Third, after the terminal is opened, type the following command:

`./monerod --log-level 2`

This command will start monerod with log level 2. Lastly, paste the output of the log to https://paste.fedoraproject.org such that the developers can investigate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

An issue of deamon not starting after a while has been already made. Maybe this is same what you are experiencing:

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/1598